# LLDB Breakpoints performance - what should I expect?

Tags: debugging, clang, llvm, lldb

I've wrote a script that adds a lot of breakpoints to my iOS project. Each breakpoint has a command that calls some logging code and continues without stopping.

During my project execution, those breakpoints are called dozens if not hundred times a second.
Unfortunately, app performance collapsed after adding those breakpoints. It's pretty much unresponsive as executing breakpoints slow things down.

**My question here is: is that normal? Is performance cost for breakpoints so significant?**

I'm pasting below part of my python script from `~/.lldb`:

```
...
for funcName in funcNames:
   breakpointCommand = f'breakpoint set -n {funcName} -f {fileName}'
   lldb.debugger.HandleCommand(breakpointCommand)
   lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('breakpoint command add --script-type python --python-function devTrackerScripts.breakpoint_callback')
```

```
def breakpoint_callback(frame, bp_loc, dict):
   lineEntry = frame.GetLineEntry()
   functionName = frame.GetDisplayFunctionName()
   expression = f'expr -- proofLog(lineEntry: "{lineEntry}", function: "{functionName}")'

   lldb.debugger.HandleCommand(expression)

   return False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that lldb with default settings runs slower than gdb on handling a breakpoint callback after hitting its corresponding breakpoint when debugging locally on Linux (lldb 10.0.0 vs gdb 9.1 on Ubuntu 20.04).

#### testcase.c

Here is the test case for the performance measurement.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int count = 0;
int fib(int n) {
    ++count;
    if(n < 2) return n;
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
int main() {
    printf("fib(16) = %d\n", fib(16));
    printf("count-1 = %d\n", count - 1);
}
```

It can be compiled with the command below to get the executable `testcase`.

```
clang -g testcase.c -o testcase
```

#### m_lldb.py

Create a Python script `m_lldb.py` with the code below for setting a breakpoint at `fib()` and a breakpoint callback `mbp_callback`.

```py
import lldb
import time
s, e = 0, 0
def mbp_callback(frame, bp_loc, dict):
    global s, e
    l, e = e, time.time()
    if s == 0: l, s = e, e
    print("Callback: %9.6fs,  Total: %9.6fs" % (e - l, e - s))
    return False
def __lldb_init_module(debugger, dict):
    tgt = debugger.GetSelectedTarget()
    bp = tgt.BreakpointCreateByName("fib")
    bp.SetScriptCallbackFunction('m_lldb.mbp_callback')
```

#### run-lldb.sh

Once the executable `testcase` and script `m_lldb.py` are ready, run the bash script below to measure the performance of lldb on handling breakpoint callback.

```sh
#!/bin/bash -x
cat << LLDBCMD > lldb.cmd
command script import m_lldb.py
breakpoint list
run
quit
LLDBCMD
lldb -s lldb.cmd -- ./testcase
```

#### m_gdb.py

Now let's create a Python script for gdb, which has the same breakpoint callback as the one for lldb.

```py
import gdb
import time
s, e = 0, 0
class MBreakpoint(gdb.Breakpoint):
    def stop(self):
        global s, e
        l, e = e, time.time()
        if s == 0: l, s = e, e
        print("Callback: %9.6fs,  Total: %9.6fs" % (e - l, e - s))
        return False
MBreakpoint("fib")
```

#### run-gdb.sh

Let's run the bash script below to measure the performance of gdb on handling breakpoint callback.

```sh
#!/bin/bash -x
cat << GDBCMD > gdb.cmd
set pagination off
source m_gdb.py
info breakpoint
run
quit
GDBCMD
gdb -x gdb.cmd --args ./testcase
```

#### Performance measurement results for handling breakpoint callback

**Server information**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

$ lldb --version
lldb version 10.0.0

$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.1-0ubuntu1) 9.1

$ grep -m1 "model name" /proc/cpuinfo
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz
```

**Results with lldb**

```c
... ...
Callback:  0.001098s,  Total:  3.509685s
Callback:  0.001106s,  Total:  3.510791s
Callback:  0.001099s,  Total:  3.511890s
Callback:  0.001097s,  Total:  3.512987s
Callback:  0.001097s,  Total:  3.514084s
Callback:  0.001107s,  Total:  3.515191s
fib(16) = 987
count-1 = 3192
Process 2527525 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000)
```

**Results with gdb**

```c
... ...
Callback:  0.000182s,  Total:  0.594779s
Callback:  0.000188s,  Total:  0.594966s
Callback:  0.000182s,  Total:  0.595149s
Callback:  0.000189s,  Total:  0.595337s
Callback:  0.000184s,  Total:  0.595521s
Callback:  0.000187s,  Total:  0.595709s
fib(16) = 987
count-1 = 3192
[Inferior 1 (process 2527714) exited normally]
```

It shows that lldb is `5.9x slower` than gdb to call a breakpoint callback when hitting an associated breakpoint.

The client-server architecture of LLDB seems to cause the poor performance above for debugging a process locally. As described in the doc at https://lldb.llvm.org/use/remote.html, `LLDB on Linux and macOS uses the remote debugging stub even when debugging a process locally`. Meanwhile heavy threading in lldb seems to be another cause of the poor performance.

Using gdbserver on localhost makes gdb run around 2x slower, but it is still much faster than debugging locally with lldb.

**run-gdbsvr.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash -x
(gdbserver --once localhost:2345 ./testcase) &
cat << GDBCMD > gdbsvr.cmd
target remote localhost:2345
set pagination off
source m_gdb.py
info breakpoint
continue
quit
GDBCMD
gdb -x ./gdbsvr.cmd --args ./testcase
```

**Results with gdbserver**

```c
... ...
Callback:  0.000384s,  Total:  1.236005s
Callback:  0.000387s,  Total:  1.236392s
Callback:  0.000383s,  Total:  1.236775s
Callback:  0.000386s,  Total:  1.237162s
Callback:  0.000383s,  Total:  1.237545s
Callback:  0.000384s,  Total:  1.237929s
fib(16) = 987
count-1 = 3192

Child exited with status 0
```

**PS:** The performance impact of the breakpoint callback should be considered also. Let's measure the impact of the execution of the callback with lldb and gdb.

**callback.py**

```py
import time
s, e = 0, 0
def stop():
    t = time.time()
    global s, e
    l, e = e, time.time()
    if s == 0: l, s = e, e
    print("Callback: %9.6fs,  Total: %9.6fs" % (e - l, e - s))
    return time.time() - t
for i in range(6):
    print("%9.6f" % stop())
```

**Run callback.py with lldb**

```c
(lldb) command script import callback.py
Callback:  0.000000s,  Total:  0.000000s
 0.000034
Callback:  0.000045s,  Total:  0.000045s
 0.000009
Callback:  0.000015s,  Total:  0.000060s
 0.000007
Callback:  0.000013s,  Total:  0.000073s
 0.000007
Callback:  0.000013s,  Total:  0.000086s
 0.000007
Callback:  0.000013s,  Total:  0.000099s
 0.000007
(lldb)
```

**Run callback.py with gdb**

```c
(gdb) source callback.py
Callback:  0.000000s,  Total:  0.000000s
 0.000023
Callback:  0.000033s,  Total:  0.000033s
 0.000010
Callback:  0.000018s,  Total:  0.000051s
 0.000010
Callback:  0.000017s,  Total:  0.000068s
 0.000009
Callback:  0.000017s,  Total:  0.000086s
 0.000009
Callback:  0.000018s,  Total:  0.000103s
 0.000009
(gdb)
```

It takes about `7~9us` for each execution of the breakpoint callback, and runs a little bit faster on lldb. The performance impact of the execution of the breakpoint callback is very limitted, `~4.8% for gdb` and `~0.6% for lldb`.

Answer (score 2):

Breakpoints are hard to make high-performance.

They involve taking an exception in the debugged process, then a context switch to the debugger to handle the exception, then single-stepping over the original instruction which involves a couple more context switches and another exception after the single step.  Then another to set the process going again.  When you are debugging an iOS device, add traffic from the iOS device to you Mac for all the context switches.

And in your case, you are also calling a function on each stop, which means compiling the expression, downloading it to the process and running the code.

It would be interesting to see whether hitting breakpoints is causing most of the slowdown, or if it's the expression evaluation that's mostly slowing you down.  If it's the expression evaluation that's dominating, then maybe you could think of another way to achieve that effect?

Comment: Thanks Jim. I deleted custom command from the breakpoints and it's still very slow so it couldn't be the biggest bottleneck. I didn't know there are so many overhead involved with breakpoints. Would you recommend any other way to "inject" some code into arbitrary functions in Swift (during runtime or build phase - but without modifying original files)?

Comment: Unless you want to do binary patching at runtime, you really have to stop in the debugger for it to do any work for you.  That's what you are trying not to do.  Binary patching is not easy to do in general.  There is a proposal to the lldb project for using binary patching at breakpoints - so for instance the condition expression on a breakpoint could be run in-process and only stop in the debugger if the conditions fails.  But this effort is still pretty far from production-ready.  There are lots of corner cases that we know will fail.  This is promising but a ways off.

Comment: Thanks Jim, that's very interesting. Will do more reading about the topic. Compilers world is so fascinating :-)